# Bootstrap Modal not displaying on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to display a simple Bootstrap Modal that says "Your message has been sent, thank you" after a form has been submitted. I am using http://formspree.io to handle the form. As per the instructions on formspree.io I've added the following HTML to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="//mysite.com/#openmodal" />
```

This is to redirect users to my modal after form submission. However, the modal is not displaying - the link is redirecting back to the top of my homepage.

Here is the HTML for the modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="openmodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: first of all: <div class="modal fade id="openmodal"> should be <div class="modal fade" id="openmodal"> there is a missing "

Comment: You could use the 'data-target' attribute on the input or button to display your modal if it doesn´t deppend on the response of the post
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openmodal">`

Check this [Bootstrap JS](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Comment: Thank you, I've added the missing quotation mark but its still not displaying.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would I go about adding the data-target attribute to the value attribute in the input tag? It just needs to be a URL for the value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a check to detect if the hash in the url exist, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.hash === "#openmodal") {
        $("#openmodal").modal("show");
    }
});
```

Comment: I added that script to the document, but still getting the same result, it doesn't load the modal dialog, any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have any JS errors in the browser's console?